# What preventative maintenance can i do to prevent rust on the axle nut

Tags: maintenance, rust

[image: Axle nut]

Hi everyone is there any specific grease or application I can use to help with preventing rust on the axle nut? I was worried due to a lot of salt being tossed on our roads in Ontario.

Comment: Where is the cap? Did you take it off for the photo or is this a new car that came with no axle nut cap? If you're not able to answer in a comment, please edit your original question to add this info.

Comment: No cap was provided, these are just steel rims i use for winter

Answer (score 0):

In your case where you have to put up with salt being used you probably aren't going to completely eliminate rusting of exposed metal. The best you can probably do is help keep it to a minimum. There are two suggestions to do this.

First, cover the threaded area with anti-seize paste. This is by no means a perfect solution. It may need to be reapplied at times, because it will flake off over time.

Second, buy some cheap hubcaps which will fit on the rims. This will help keep the road salts off of it in the first place. Again, it won't keep all of it off, but it'll keep the majority of it off of the bare metal parts.

You may consider painting the area with some neutral colored spray paint. This may be a little bit more problematic than using anti-seize, but will keep it from getting the schmutz on it and would most likely last the longest and work the best. Why I say it is problematic is, if you need to take the nut off the axle at any time, it might make it a little bit harder to remove the nut. If you do use this method, make sure you clean the threads as good as possible so the paint will stick.  Also remember to hit both sides (top/bottom) of the nut, lol. Most people wouldn't forget, but thought I'd throw it out there, lol.